# Magento Different Behave in Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, nginx, url-rewriting

One server same source code Magento Enterprise , if i run it in Apache after post request one Get request received , but in nginx not work , and shows me page not found 404.

I check it using firebug in Firefox .

URL : /customer/account/create/

After click Subbmit it redirect to

URL : /customer/account/index/ = and user longed page come

But in Nginx

URL : /customer/account/create/

After click Subbmit it redirect to

http://52.88.205.17/customer/account/createpost/  = 404 page not found

Apache Server default configuration and htaccess is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

And Nginx Configuration is

```
server {

        listen       80;
        server_name  http://52.88.205.17;

        location / {
        root /var/www/html/src/;
        index  index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        }

        location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/html/src/;
                }

        #location  /index.php/admin      { deny all;}

        #Disable .htaccess and Hidden Files
        location  /. { return 404;      }

        location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/html/src/;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem Increasing PHP Buffer Size

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```